# Setting oracle NLS_LANG for a JPA query

Tags: oracle, jpa, nls-lang

I need to access an oracle database view that require a certain nls_lang to be set - if it's not, an index will not be used and the database will lock up pretty much forever. I know this is bad joke design wise, but it is nothing I can change.

I can change nls_lang by setting the system variables `user.country` and/or`user.language`, which will correctly change the nls_lang. However, this will affect my application in unknown ways, and even worse: other applications on the same server. Simply put this is not a possible solution.

**So how can I set nls_lang for a single JPA native query, while keeping another locale set for the server**? It needs to be a native query because I'm selecting from a view that does not contain a PK, which is required by Entities.

I've tried

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("ALTER SESSION set NLS_LANGUAGE = 'American'").executeUpdate();
```

before running my query, but it does not seem to have effect, probably because the query is done in a different session. Perhaps in theory I could set `Locale.setDefault()` temporarily, and restore it after the query, but that would give concurrency problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you begin a transaction first and use the same EntityManager for the setting and query.

Comment: This is a JTA entity manager, so I can't control the transaction.

Comment: Then ensure you are in a JTA transaction.

Comment: I am, the alter session doesn't seem to work so I assumed there was a new session in the 2nd query.

Comment: Nevermind, alter session works now with normal JTA container managed transactions.. dont know why it did not before.